# How do you use JQuery to load HTML fragment from another file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried using the method described at w3 schools  but it seems to only work in FireFox
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax.asp

I used the example provided on the [Try It](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax1)

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").load('test1.txt');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I just set it to run onload instead on after clicking. It did work there but when I make my own page it only works in FireFox.

Edit: Chrome just has security to prevent local file access it works on a server.

If anyone knows how this would work in older IE versions it would be a help

Comment: Are you executing this code in the context of a web server or just a static HTML file on your hard drive somewhere?

Comment: I took your code and tested it in Firefox, Chrome and IE (9) and it worked fine in all three.

Comment: When you test, open your file in http://, not in file://. Of course you need a local webserver to do that.

Comment: I figured out that my problem is actually on the IE 8 browser Chrome just has local file security that prevents doing it without a server. Does anyone know how to make it work in IE 8 or older?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to take a look at [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function. It can use cache and it's better then using the "sub-alias" `$.get`.

Comment: Why should this be better, it's just a shorthand for $.ajax with default settings

Comment: @RobAngelier You said it, default settings.. by default.

Comment: It depends on the situation. If you don't need all the possible options, i would prefer the shorthand $.get

Answer (score 2):

Your example works in the Chrome 18. 
You can try this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('test1.txt', function(response) {
        $('div').html(response);
    })
});
```

Comment: this does the same thing doesn't it? yes it has the same results.

Comment: works the same as the load function yes in modern browsers not in IE 8

Comment: I tried it in IE8 (8.0.6001.18702) and it works, BTW your code works too